# Oracle database link

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ora-01017

I'm currently using Windows Authentication with 2 Oracle servers - SP3DSMP1 & SP3DSMP4. I created a database link on SMP1 to connect to SMP4 as:

SQL> create public database link LINK_SMP4
  2  connect to CURRENT_USER
  3  using 'SP3DSMP4';

Database link created.

However when I try to do a query, I get the error:

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: Can one Oracle server authenticate to another Oracle server using Windows auth? Too lazy to look at actual docs now, but I doubt it, and this would be the first thing I'd check.

Answer (score 7):

Credentials are not passed over the dblink connection.

When creating a `CURRENT_USER` dblink, a trust should be established between the databases. This requires setting up an enterprise domain, adding the databases to it, setting an `SSL` link between the databases and making the link `CURRENT_USER` enabled.

See here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/network.101/b10772/asoeuscf.htm